# How to solve Python fatal error: init_sys_streams

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, libraries, filepath

I am quite new to python and Anaconda. I was moving some files in the Anaconda directory when I launch spyder and I get the following error:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\io.py", line 52, in 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Lib\collections\abc.py", line 1, in 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 9, in 
ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCMeta' from 'abc' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Lib\collections\abc.py)
```

Would anyone know how to deal with it?

Thank you

Comment: _I was moving some files in the Anaconda directory_ Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your project has a file named abc.py. Rename it to abc_xxx.py then  it will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file named either abc.py or abc.pyc in your working directory or PYTHONPATH and that one shadows the stdlib abc module.

Change the name and you're good to go